# how to display a specific wordpress menu?

Tags: customization, menus

Below is my code:

```
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu', _('My Custom Header Menu'),
            'theme_location' => 'my_custom_location', 
            ) );
```

---

And as result, I obtain all Wordpress page's menu link instead of the menu of My Custom Header Menu.

Comment: Your parameters array is a mix of standalone entries and key value pairs, are you sure `'menu', _(...), 'theme_location' => '...'` is what you intended? mixing `[1,2,3]` and `[ 'foo' => 'bar' ]` style array items is not normal

Comment: Also, are you trying to render a specific menu theme location? You're specifying both `menu` and `theme_location` which is a paradox, "show this specific menu, no actually show the menu at this theme menu location"

Comment: My custom menu theme location is a hook. And I successfully come out to display menu items over there. Now I need to specify to wp_nav_menu, to display only the menu items of My Custom Header Menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Register your navigation menu** 
Add this code to your functions.php file.

```
function my_custom_new_menu() {
      register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_new_menu' );
```

**Create new menu** 
You can now go to Appearance » Menus page in your WordPress admin and try to create or edit a new menu. You will see ‘My Custom Menu’ as theme location option. 
**Display new menu**

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu') 
);
```

Comment: my-custom-menu in REGISTER_NAV_MENU is different from THEME_LOCATION's one reason why

Answer (score 1):

First check if you have already registred a menu location with the same name :

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'my_custom_location' => 'My Custom location',
) );
```

Secondly, i don't think you need this : 'menu', _('My Custom Header Menu'), and instead just keep your code as bellow :

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'my_custom_location', 
) );
```